# DocuSign is getting a 400 error on production baseUrl while demo is working fine

Tags: docusignapi

I encountered this problem today. It was working since last year, then started to throw error like

```
[400] Error connecting to the API 
(https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/f0332a4a-528a-4f7f-a506-f1a9be016ca1/envelopes)"
```

When I test the integration in dev mode. It works just fine. I think the api endpoint has a problem. This endpoint `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi` for demo works flawlessly.

The base URL could also be the problem. Is anybody from DocuSign team able to verify this? I can't seem to find the reason why. I tried to regenerate token and use it but no joy. Again it works fine in `demo` but not on any production `baseUrl`.

The code is written in PHP and I'm using the [PHP sdk version of the docusign](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client).

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to accomplish w/this API call? i.e: is it a GET of all envelopes from a certain date?

Comment: I see couple of problems here. The accountId (f0332a4a-528a-4f7f-a506-f1a9be016ca1) is not present in the Docusign system.   I also see two requests sent to Docusign with the HTTP Method HEAD. This does not resolve to a valid endpoint so Docusign is correctly throwing the error. Please check the parameters you are passing along with the endpoint you are calling.

Comment: @CodingDawg the accountId is made up. Was just trying to protect it somehow. I use the PHP SDK to do this. I was using the `createEnvelope` method to create an envelope. And when it goes to check the accountId that error is thrown. The weird thing is that it happens on my other account but not on the newly created one. Is their any specific reason for account limitation or something? An account who created the app (via the admin page) also work without a problem.

Comment: @LuisScott no I use the `createEnvolope` method on the SDK to create the envelope. It works fine on some account, but others don't which throws that error. Do note that I'm creating the document data it's just that the template is different. Is there any explanation to that?

Comment: @KennethPalaganas Can you please post your complete code and the line where you are getting the error.  With the information you have given it is hard to pinpoint your exact issue.

Comment: @CodingDawg It's quite long but I'll summarize it. Here's a pastebin version. http://pastebin.com/ZUM7Zehy There's a try/catch on the whole code. The error is catch from that block. The accountId and baseUri is from the `/oauth/userinfo` endpoint. Like I said it's working but on some account only. Is docusign does not allow free user's maybe?